# How to build app ionic/cordova app with iOS SDK 17 instead of 16?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

[image: apple email]

We just got this e-mail from Apple saying that our app is being built with iOS SDK 16.2 and we should use iOS 17 SDK, but I'm struggling to find how to actually do that.

I've read online that the SDK version is tied to Xcode and we're using the latest version, 15.2.

I thought about updateing "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0" to a newer version, but I'm not sure if that's what's needed.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? I'm needing to do the same.

Comment: I updated Cordova-ios to 7.0.1 which is the latest release and still the app is built using iOS 16.2 SDK.

Comment: @ScottD I don't have access to it so someone else picked up the task, but apparently it's an option on the ionic dashboard when you can chose to build the app for a specific xcode version. So when you choose the newest version it tells you what version of tools it needs: node 18, cordova 12, ionic 7, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your build environment, but it sounds like you need to set your Xcode command line tools to use Xcode 15.x.

You can try something like this:

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

**For me I needed to have Xcode 15 selected for CI on Azure Pipeline. This got it working for me.**

Use this image...

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-13
```

And add these steps...

```
- bash: ls -la /Applications/Xcode*
  displayName: List Xcode versions

- bash: /bin/bash -c "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.2.app/Contents/Developer"
  displayName: xcode-select Xcode_15.2 iOS 17 SDK
```

Of course the list Xcode versions is optional, but I needed to discover what versions the image included.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to it so someone else picked up the task, but apparently it's an option on the ionic dashboard when you can chose to build the app for a specific xcode version. So when you choose the newest version it tells you what version of tools it needs: node 18, cordova 12, ionic 7, etc